# mysql select in () not really work with list in table field

Tags: mysql

Table pakets

| id | cust | ids | expire |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 58267 | 3,4 | 2024-06-05 |
| ... |  |  |  |

```
SELECT id 
FROM packets 
WHERE cust='58267' and 3 in (ids) and now() <= expire 
order by 1 desc
limit 1;

+------+
| id   | 
+------+
| 99   |
+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

if i do:

```
SELECT id 
FROM packets 
WHERE cust='58267' and 4 in (ids) and now() <= expire 
order by 1 desc 

Empty set
```

Should be

```
+------+
| id   | 
+------+
| 99   |
+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

What i am missing??? Thanks for all tipps or hints.

Comment: You need to use `FIND_IN_SET(4, ids)`

Comment: `4 in (ids)` converts `3,4` to an integer, resulting in `3`, and then does `4 in (3)`, which fails.

Comment: Thanks. That do the trick.